# Can Bitbucket share the same rsa key as Github? Plus 2 more related questions

Tags: ssh, key, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

1. I have successfully added an SSH key in github, can I use the same ssh key "id_rsa" and "id_rsa.pub" in bitbucket?
2. Do I need to include the "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" at the beginning and "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" at the end of the ssh key?
3. Do I also need the "host address", and where do you find it on a mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can add the same ***public*** key to GitHub, Bitbucket, GitLab, and whatever other boxes you want that support SSH connections. Don't put the private key anyplace but your own system; if somebody else gets the private key then the keypair is worthless.
2. What exactly are you trying to do that has you pasting private keys around the Internet?
3. No, that isn't necessary.